# WooCommerce - Making a checkout field required

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

on my baked goods site,  I have WooCommerce installed and another plugin called Order Delivery Date for WooCommerce.

I installed the second plugin so my customers would be able to choose a delivery date for their items, however, I am trying to make the form field a required field. So far, I've just been able to make the field look like a required field, but have not figured out how to make sure that it is actually enforced. Any ideas?

Also, if anyone is familiar with WooCommerce, do you know how I would be able to make it so that customers receive this delivery date information in their order confirmation emails?

Thank you in advance!

My site: www.monpetitfour.com

Answer (score 1):

You should try to had something like that :

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    // You can make your own control here
    if ( ! $_POST[ 'e_deliverydate' ] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please select a delivery date' ), 'error' );
}
```

For the email, the easiest is to save the meta value ( I think it's already done by your plugin). Then you need to copy the template email (customer-processing-order.php) on your theme and change in the template :

```
 <?php  $delivery_date = get_post_meta( $order->id, 'custom_field_date', true); 
 // If the plugin is well developed, you can't directly use magic getters : 
 // $delivery_date = $order->e_deliverydate;
 // Can only by use if the post meta start with _
?>
 Your delivery date is <?php echo $delivery_date ?>
```

You can also use

```
date_i18n( woocommerce_date_format(), strtotime( $delivery_date ) );
```

In order to format the date correctly.

On the code above, you just need to find the name of the custom field used by the plugin ( you can search easily on the table wp_postmeta searching by an existing order (should be _e_deliverydate).

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to your theme's functions.php file

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
// Check if set, if its not set add an error.
if ( ! $_POST['e_deliverydate'] )
wc_add_notice( __( 'Please select a delivery date.' ), 'error' );
}
```

Now to get the email to show the custom field,

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys', 'my_woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys');

function my_woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys( $keys ) {
    $keys['Delivery Date'] = '_e_deliverydate';
    return $keys;
}
```

**EDIT :** Seems the field value isn't being saved to the database, try saving it explicitly

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['e_deliverydate'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_e_deliverydate', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['e_deliverydate'] ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So I added both to my theme's functions.php, but only the first set of code (for the required field) works. The second part in the email (or the resulting confirmation page on the site) don't show the delivery date that was chosen. Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of Woocommerce are you using? Check the database to see if the wp_postmeta table has an entry for the _e_deliverydate for the given order.

Comment: Okay I just checked the wp_postmeta table and there's no _e_deliverydate. There's only Delivery Date. And I am using Woocommerce 2.2.8 and Order Delivery Date for Woocommerce 1.2

Comment: Seems quite strange that the plugin isn't saving the data, anyways have updated my answer, see if that helps.

Comment: When I add that to my functions.php, it gives me the following error result: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta() (previously declared in /home/content/06/11291806/html/secondsite/wp-content/plugins/order-delivery-date-for-woocommerce/order_delivery_date.php:129) in /home/content/06/11291806/html/secondsite/wp-content/themes/vantage/functions.php on line 402

Comment: Ok, so the plugin has already declared that function. Which means that it should save the field value. Not sure why that isn't happening.

Answer (score 0):

```html
/* Please try the below code for validation error while clicking on place order on the checkout page */

/* #site-content you can used also body unique class*/

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#site-content").on("click", '#place_order', function() {
        jQuery("input").each(function() {
            if (jQuery(this).is(":empty")) {
                jQuery('.validate-required input, .validate-required select').trigger('validate');
            } else {
                jQuery(this).find('span.error').hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```